# Sidebar Navigation not taking up full height of website

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

So i'm running into a issue with a small simple website i'm building. I have a sidebar navigation with a dark background. On pages with content that is longer than the navigation content I need that background to expand as long as the main content. You can see what i'm talking about when you view the page.

http://germantown.acscreative.com/2015/Appaloosa2015/_build_093015/transition.php

If you scroll down you can see the black background stops when the content for the nav is done.

I am using foundation 5 for my frameworks.

```
<div class="medium-12 columns sidebar">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="img/m-logo.png"></a>
    <p>ROB WIEDEFELD</p>
        <?php include 'navs/nav.php';?>
</div>

.sidebar {
    background: #2f3536;
    max-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 900px;
}
```

I have tried a combination of min-height max-height overflow properties and just can seem to find the right combination

Comment: It seems to be working already? I'm not experiencing the problem you are describing. What browser and operating system are you viewing it in?

Comment: Yes, i actually JUST fixed the issue. Thanks for taking a look though

Answer (score 0):

So I found the fix myself and thought I would share. Foundation has this handy JS feature call "Equalizer" that worked perfect for my solution.

Probably the easy way out but work.